# preg_match acting very strange

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am using `preg_match()` to extract pieces of text from a variable, and let's say the variable looks like this:

```
[htmlcode]This is supposed to be displayed[/htmlcode]

middle text

[htmlcode]This is also supposed to be displayed[/htmlcode]
```

i want to extract the contents of the `[htmlcode]`'s and input them into an array. i am doing this by using `preg_match()`.

```
preg_match('/\[htmlcode\]([^\"]*)\[\/htmlcode\]/ms', $text, $matches);
foreach($matches as $value){
return $value . "<br />";
}
```

The above code outputs

```
[htmlcode]This is supposed to be displayed[/htmlcode]middle text[htmlcode]This is also supposed to be displayed[/htmlcode]
```

instead of

1. [htmlcode]This is supposed to be displayed[/htmlcode]
2. [htmlcode]This is also supposed to be displayed[/htmlcode]

and if have offically run out of ideas

Comment: Where is `preg_replace`?

Comment: Actually, this is not strange at all ;) see the answers.

Comment: @hjpotter92 good point, however the problem is in the regex, rather than the PHP function used.

Comment: @hjpotter92 ah, sorry :P been trying to solve this all day, been working with preg_match and preg_replace and its now very late so my brain is a little confused :P Edited

Comment: Everyone is saying add a `?` which is true but you could also use the `U` modifier, note that it's a capital letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained already; the `*` pattern is greedy. Another thing is to use `preg_match_all()` function. It'll return you a multi-dimension array of matched content.

```
preg_match_all('#\[htmlcode\]([^\"]*?)\[/htmlcode\]#ms', $text, $matches);
foreach( $matches[1] as $value ) {
```

And you'll get this: http://codepad.viper-7.com/z2GuSd

Answer (score 3):

A `*` grouper is greedy, i.e. it will eat everything until **last** `[/htmlcode]`. Try replacing `*` with non-greedy `*?`.

Answer (score 2):

`*` is by default greedy, `([^\"]*?)` (notice the added `?`) should make it lazy.

- [What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

Look at this piece of code:

```
preg_match('/\[htmlcode\]([^\"]*)\[\/htmlcode\]/ms', $text, $matches);
foreach($matches as $value){
return $value . "<br />";
}
```

Now, if your pattern works fine and all is ok, you should know:

- `return` statement will break all loops and will exit the function.
- The first element in matches is the whole match, the whole string. In your case `$text`

So, what you did is returned the first big string and exited the function.

I suggest you can check for desired results:

`$matches[1]` and `$matches[2]`